# Why the following equation has no discrete solutions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

can somebody please help me understand why the following equation has no discrete integer solutions ?

$7x^2 - 1 = y^2$

Comment: $0^2 \equiv 0\pmod{7},~1^2\equiv 1\pmod{7},~2^2\equiv 4\pmod{7},~3^2\equiv 2\pmod{7},\dots$

Comment: Reducing the equation modulo $7$, we get $-1 \equiv y^2$. By checking all possible residue classes modulo $7$, we can see that no such $y$ exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that

$$x^2\equiv0\mod 4 \implies7x^2 - 1 \equiv 3\mod 4$$

$$x^2\equiv1\mod 4 \implies7x^2 - 1 \equiv 2\mod 4$$

but $y^2=0,1 \mod 4$.

Answer (score 0):

For even $x$ we have $$y^2=4q-1$$which is not of form $8q'+1$.

For odd $x$ we obtain$$y^2=8q+6$$which is not equal to $4q'$.